# Error: undefined Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Been searching for a solution about the error module on navigation. I've tried reset-cache, deleting nodu_modules, reinstall the module but still its not working.

Full details of the error

```
Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/native` from `src/App.js`: @react-navigation/native could not be found within the project.
```

**Package.json**

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.9",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.11"
```

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention the platform you are using. There seems to be some MacOS specifics.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Answer (score 3):

in your package.json add "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5", and then run npm install @react-navigation/native

Comment: After installing @react-navigation/native my issue was resolved. Thank you @neelam soni

Answer (score 1):

Package that you use react-navigation is modular. So in order to make it work you have to install specific components.

In your case you have to run:

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```

The reason for this kind of behavior is that in many apps you need only one type of navigation. This would mean you are installing unused code and clutter your bundle.

In order to clear the bundler cache you can do something like this:

npm < 6.0 and RN < 0.50:

```
 watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* &&
 rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && 
 npm start -- --reset-cache
```

npm >= 6.0 and RN >= 0.50:

```
 watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
 rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force &&
 npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

This should do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs --force
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install package. npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Try this
“npm i @react-navigation/bottom-tabs”

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean
```

Ensure that you have `@react-navigation/native` and its dependencies then install `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`:

**Dependencies:**

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
```

**In your expo managed project directory, run:**

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

**(Or) In your bare react project directory, run:**

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

**Then**

```
yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```