# Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs " from "App.js

Tags: react-native

i was using stack navigator , i was not getting any error but I switch on tab navigator I am getting error I have folder of bottom tab in nodemodule I have restart my app delete nodemodule folder but no luck please help Mr why I am getting this error

```
const Tweets = ({ navigation }) => (
  <ExpoScreen>
    <Text>Tweets</Text>
    <Button
      title="View Tweet"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TweetDetails", { id: 1 })}
    />
  </ExpoScreen>
);

const TweetDetails = ({ route }) => (
  <ExpoScreen>
    <Text>Tweets details {route.params.id}</Text>
    <Link />
  </ExpoScreen>
);

const Account = () => (
  <ExpoScreen>
    <Text>Account details </Text>
  </ExpoScreen>
);


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNaviator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Tweets} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={Account} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNaviator />
      {/* <StackNavigator /> */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

}
[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. Have you tried what is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235733/error-undefined-unable-to-resolve-module-react-navigation-bottom-tabs ?

Comment: tried but no luck

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, did you have any luck on resolving this issue? Please share if you did.

Answer (score 0):

npm install && npm start --reset-cache

This Worked for me.